# Android external usb camera

Tags: android, camera, usb, kernel

I rooted android galaxy nexus. I don't see any video devices under dev folder checked through adb shell.

I am trying to use External USB camera http://brain.cc.kogakuin.ac.jp/research/usb-e.html.

Modified Kernel settings and build custom zImage , After unpacking boot.img and replacing zImage then repacked to new-boot.img. I flashed with new boot.img. Once i run sample camera app from above mentioned url cannot see any video frames. I think it could because there is no video device under /dev normally device should have /dev/video0,1 so on.

Any body can help or show some direction ?